# How to install proprietary drivers via CD-ROM on a netbook?

Tags: drivers, cd-drive

I need to install the internet card drivers on my netbook the problem is that it doesn't have CD tray so I can't install them via the Cd or at least I don't know where to mount the ISO so Ubuntu recognizes it so I can put the Proprietary Drivers. So is there any other way? Or where can I mount the ISO?

Comment: What do you mean by 'privative'? Is this the name of the company/network card or do you mean 'proprietary'? From a dictionary: privative (1) Causing deprivation, lack, or loss.

Comment: oh sorry y mean proprietary, the drivers that are not open-source

Comment: Can you provide more specific details in your question? Are you trying to mount the CD for the proprietary drivers or for Ubuntu? What is the maker of the hardware you're trying to install?

Comment: I want to install the propietary drivers that come on the Ubuntu Cd. I know that the drivers are in the Ubuntu 10.10 cd because when in Software Origins I check the box that says install software from Ubuntu Cd and I go to active the propietary drivers it says that I can active them but it tolds me to insert the Cd, but as I am on a netbook I dont have Cd Tray.

Comment: What is the name and model of your wireless card? Seems odd to me that you have got it on a CD since (unless these are windows drivers used through ndiswrapper) needs to be recompiled at every kernel update. Is'nt it possible to download the drivers from the manufacturers website?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, taken from here [How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository)

If you want to use the ISO image as a software source without burning it, the process will be a bit more complicated. You will need to open a terminal Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal and run these commands:

sudo mkdir /aptoncd-mountpoint

sudo mount /media/USB/aptoncd.iso ~/aptoncd-mountpoint -oloop

sudo apt-cdrom -d=/aptoncd-mountpoint add

(source: http://www.debianhelp.org/node/10486)

Answer (score 1):

You can install .deb packages by double-clicking them, so just install them that way from the mounted .iso image?

Answer (score 0):

When it asks for your cd, you can mount the ubuntu iso from the website, in the way that the other 2 people have told you.

Once it is mounted, you can add the mounted iso in software sources as a software cd. Then you should be able to install from there.

Do you have the option to get internet using an ethernet cable? That would be the easiest option for you.