# apt-get keeps saying to check Internet, while I have a good connection 

Tags: updates, update-manager, repository, software-sources

I need to check if I have updates for Ubuntu. I think it is 12.04

As you can see this is what it says:

```
Failed to download repository information  Check your Internet connection.

Details:

W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the exact error message, but the obvious question now is: did you check your internet connection and what was the result? You could open a browser and see if your internet connection works.

Comment: It appears that the main repos responded, so i doubt some proxy thingy here. <wild guess>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I recommend checking your internet connection. Just open Firefox and see if your start page loads.
If you are not connected to the internet, try to connect to a Wifi network. If your computer has no Wifi capabilities, or lacks the necessary drivers, plug an ethernet wire into your computer.

Comment: This message is for: (Jaxkr) Well thats the problem and i only have Chromium Web Browser, i just click and my WIFI is fine!!!!

Comment: wifi is fine!!!

Comment: OK EVERYBODY THANKS TO JAXKR I PLUGGED IN A ETHERNET WIRE IN TO MY INTERNET ROUTER (BT INFINITY) INTO MY COMPUTER (DESKTOP) AND IT WORKED SO JAXAR FIXED IT

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and after changing the server from the update manager (from my country to us or main server) it worked just fine. Try a server near you or the main one and see if it works

[image]

Edit:
Uncheck CD-ROM
[image]

Comment: This Message is for: (Remus Rigo), Sorry mate that dosnt work!       Details are above on the description above

Comment: open a terminal and try to ping google (ping -c 3 www.google.com) and post the result

Comment: luca@luca-oneTwo-L5861:~$ ping -c 3 www.google.com
PING www.l.google.com (173.194.66.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from we-in-f147.1e100.net (173.194.66.147): icmp_req=1 ttl=44 time=35.4 ms
64 bytes from we-in-f147.1e100.net (173.194.66.147): icmp_req=2 ttl=44 time=34.6 ms
64 bytes from we-in-f147.1e100.net (173.194.66.147): icmp_req=3 ttl=44 time=37.7 ms

--- www.l.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 34.663/35.976/37.770/1.313 ms
luca@luca-oneTwo-L5861:~$

Comment: go to: Ubuntu software center - > Edit -> Software Sources and uncheck CD-ROM

Comment: There is no Edit, and can i remind you my system is 12.05

Comment: The edit is available from the menu in the main bar [as in the screenshot]

Comment: i did it but i didnt work!

Answer (score 1):

#### What those errors are saying

I have seen your error message and The problem is for the deactivated PPA. The PPA is no longer exists!. You can check this manually by trying to go to this link

> http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources

This is the link, from which apt trying to load the source index file. As the PPA is offline, It is giving a 404 error. Though Your internet is fine.

Also Try to go to this [PPA's home page in launchpad.](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/java/) You can see that, there is not activity or build for your Ubuntu version i.e 12.04 aka Precise Pangolin.

And The error with cdrom's are for the fact that, those entries becomes invalid. You have to re add those cdroms. I am giving solutions to both problems.

#### Solution for the error with PPA

The solution is remove the software source line from your system.

- First check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file by opening it in a terminal with command `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` to see any line with containing that link. It should look like this.

  ```
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu precise main
  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu precise main
  ```

  If you see any line, containing this, remove the line completely and exactly only that line.
- If there wasn't any line like that, the PPA source file is in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. In that case, remove that file by the following command

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ferramroberto-java-precise.list
  ```

#### Solution for the error regarding CDROM entries

- Open a terminal and type `software-properties-gtk` and hit `Enter`
- In the opened window, in **Other software** tab, Click on the "cdrom" entries and and hit **Remove** button to remove corrupted apt cdrom source.

  [image]

That's it. Try now `sudo apt-get update` to see the error was removed.

If you want to add a CDROM again as a Software-Source, See these Links.

- [How to use .iso image as a software repository?](https://askubuntu.com/a/135395/61218)
- [Ubuntu help about AptCdrom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom)
- [Manual page for Apt-Cdrom](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-cdrom)

Answer (score 0):

Are you conected to internet? if so and guive you that error, try this: Try to change the server selecting update manager, definitions,downloading from, then select a server more near you. and then try to check your updates again.

Comment: Thats exactly what i told Remus Rigo, that dosnt work, sorry mate    Details are above on description above

Comment: Sorry mate! I didn't read correctly your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Xubuntu 12.04, for several days. Changing the server and unchecking the CD-ROM box indicated in previous answers did not solve it.

I opened the Synaptic Package Manager and clicked on Settings > Repositories. Under the Ubuntu tab, the same CD-ROM box appeared and was unchecked. Under the Other Software tab there were a half-dozen lines mentioning CD-ROM. I unchecked, then Removed them all. Closed that window and clicked Reload on the main window. This seems to have solved the problem for me, since the Update Manager now says "The package information was just updated" (it used to be 10 days out-of-date and refused to update when I had the problem). Now clicking the Check button in the Update Manager finishes without complaints about the Precise cdrom.

Comment: it didnt work sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before. It may due to network proxies. You may check the network proxies!

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you edited it to explain how to check the network proxies.