# Is it possible to use the Raring install image as a package repo (like the old alternate CD)?

Tags: installation, package-management, repository, iso

I use Kubuntu and recently upgraded to Raring directly from Precise.

Until Precise, I always installed the OS using the alternate CD and not the desktop CD, because I could later on mount the image and use it as an offline package repo. For instance if I remove a package installed by the default installer and later I want to install it again, I can just install it from the ISO without needing to download it again.

However, since Quantal the alternate CD no longer exists, so I am not sure how to set up the installed image as a local repo. I mean, doing find . -name "*.deb" inside the ISO tree after loopmounting it only shows a few packages like libc6 gcc and such and not the full set of packages that are actually installed -- I presume they are included in pre-installed form inside casper/filesystem.squashfs.

Given this situation, is it or is it not possible to use the Raring install images as offline repos? If yes, how?

Thank you!

Edit: Quite a few people marked this as a dup of: [How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository) but the steps outlined there (that thread is from 2010) do not work with the Raring image. IIUC they would work only with the alternate images and they are not available any more. So anyway I tried those instructions and did:

> $ mount | grep loop
>
> /mnt/sda8/samjnaa/ai/ubuntu/raring/kubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso on /mnt/loop0 type iso9660 (ro)
>
> $ sudo apt-cdrom -d /mnt/loop0/ add
>
> Using CD-ROM mount point /mnt/loop0/
>
> Unmounting CD-ROM
>
> Waiting for disc...
>
> Please insert a Disc in the drive and press enter
>
> Mounting CD-ROM...
>
> E: Failed to mount the cdrom.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but if you disconnect from the internet, and have the CD in your tray, it might just work.  Basing this off the the option seen in the following screenshot. http://i.sajanp.com/20130625214425.png

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply -- but LOL who uses actual physical CDs these days -- I have hardly ever used them for installing Ubuntu. See https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/211987. I mean, my question was using the ISO image as a local repo.

Comment: @jamadagni Who uses physical CDs/DVDs these days?  Most people born before 1995 or so.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question, You can check the answer over [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/333620/52435)

To summarize the steps I described there,

You need to make a folder in /media and mount the iso to that folder. You can do so by running the following command as root

```
mount /path/to/iso /media/mountFOlder -o loop
```

Next you should add the following lines to your /etc/fstab file (Always make a backup before making any changes to this file)

```
/path/to/iso /media/mountFolder      iso9660 loop,ro,user,noauto 0 0
```

Then you need to make an entry in /etc/apt/sources.list pointing to the repos in the iso. I don't know what that should be for ubuntu, but for debian it should be

```
deb file:/media/mountFolder/ wheezy main contrib
```

where wheezy is the name of the current release of debian and main and contrib are the two repositorys. You should comment out everything else.

Next you should run `apt-get update` as root and then any installation using `apt-get install packageName` should run without internet now.

That's all. If you want to auto mount the iso everytime you boot, you should remove user,noauto from the entry you made in /etc/fstab