# Using disk image files (.iso) as a repository

Tags: lubuntu, repository, iso

I am currently using Lubuntu 13.10 and I have made an iso file with AptonCD to backup the programs (with their dependencies of course) that I may need when I reinstall Lubuntu. My problem is that I am using a netbook and thus I have no CD or DVD reader. Thats why I cannot burn the iso file to a CD or DVD and plug it in to use it as a repository. Is there a way to use the iso file directly as a repository? I know that this question has already been answered in [How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository) however when I run   ***sudo apt-cdrom -d=/aptoncd-mountpoint add***   as posted in the answer of the former question I get

```
Using CD-ROM mount point /cdrom/
Unmounting CD-ROM
Waiting for disc...
Please insert a Disc in the drive and press enter 
Mounting CD-ROM...
E: Failed to mount the cdrom.
E: No CD-ROM could be auto-detected or found using the default mount point.
```

I strongly believe that I have not done anything wrong. So what I wanted to ask is:
How can I fix this if possible? and How can I use an iso file as a repository if I am not able to do the steps presented in the answer of [How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository) Thanks in advence

Comment: Would help if you update your question with the exact commands you've run.

Comment: have you mount your .ISO first ?

Comment: yes I mounted my iso as shown in the link I gave in my question. In fact I tried almost everything shown in <http://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository>

Answer (score 0):

Add option -m to apt-cdrom command.