# Offline Upgrade of Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, offline

I'm trying to do an offline upgrade of ubuntu without using cdrom.

I tried somne of options listed in the below links :

[How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image)

[How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository)

The issue I'm facing is that when i boot from a "live" usb of ubuntu 13.10, GUI does not provide an option upgrade existing installation of ubuntu 13.04.

- When mounting the Ubuntu Live ISO inside existing Ubuntu installation
  and adding it to the software sources list, I'm able to update
  individual package, but not the entire release.
- Specifically, when I go offline and try the do-release upgrade from
  Terminal, it is not able to find any updates to OS.

Can you please guide me to upgrade 13.04 to 13.10 from the mounted iso ?

**Note :**

My PC already has windows 7 and Windows 8 installed. It loads off the Windows 7 bootloader and is linked to grub by using Easy BCD.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of making a local apt repository is to use a given media as a resource for your packages, and this is one half.

After you have done this and updated `apt` with `sudo apt-get update` you can do an upgrade to a new release with

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But beware that this is not granted to work, if you can't solve a dependency you are likely to break your system, `apt` heavily relies on multiple repositories and online resources to solve all the dependencies.

Another alternative is [apt-cdrom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom).