# Where would I find the debs for the repos on a livecd?

Tags: wireless, repository, live-cd

My ethernet cable broke so I can ONLY connect to wifi for internet at the moment, but I need to do a fresh install as I just got a new ssd. I don't have any removable media on hand either as I gave my old hard drive to a friend and all of my flash drives are either getting errors or are with other people. I need to know where the bcmwl-kernel-source deb file is on a livecd so I can install, open the livecd in a file manager, and install that package so I get wifi. I've tried making it a source and such but it hasn't worked in the past and I don't want to have to deal with that so I want to know where it would be for a 64b system on a 64b livecd.

Comment: Better try: http://askubuntu.com/q/4694/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the package files are located in the `pool` directory:

```
$ sudo mount ~/Downloads/OS/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt
$ cd /mnt
$ ls
autorun.inf  boot  casper  dists  EFI  install  isolinux  md5sum.txt  pics  pool  preseed  README.diskdefines  ubuntu  wubi.exe
$ ls pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
1.1M pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

The layout of `pool` is like the layout of `pool` in online repositories.

The `md5sum.txt` contains the hashes of all the packages, so you can grep it to quickly find out where a package is:

```
$ grep bcmwl md5sum.txt 
3a9fca958bc1e3e78acfae7d040b95da  ./pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

The file listing on the image server ([ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.list](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.list)) also contains the path to all files included.

Comment: where is pool? I can't find it in mnt

Comment: never mind, I found it

Comment: @sbergeron well, did you find the package?

Comment: I need to install and reboot but I'll tell you by morning