# How to install ubuntu-desktop from boottable usb

Tags: 14.04, usb, lamp

Please help me on this.

Situation is: I install and using tasksel to install Lamp Server, but when tasksel installation finished, it remove my ubuntu-desktop. I cannot view the gui anymore.

I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4.

I have a bootable USB which has Ubuntu 14.04. Now I want to reinstall ubuntu-desktop but my network is very slow. I want to install it using ubutu-desktop in the USB.

Please show me if there are any possible ways

Thanks in advance.

Nathan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu to a Flash Drive via Startup Disk Creator:

Note: Back up ALL data from your Flash Drive before proceeding!

Insert your Ubuntu CD (**or if you have iso file than dont do this step**) and restart your computer, booting from the Live CD

Insert a 1GB or larger USB flash drive

Navigate to **System > Administration > Startup Disk Creator**: Start Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator

[image]

Next,

**if you have iso file of Ubuntu than select from source disk iso file. than further proceed.**

(1) Select your Flash Drive from Disk to use

(2) Choose to Erase Disk (Make sure you have backed up any important data first) Erase Disk (Make sure you have data backed up first)

[image]
Now,

(1) Select the partition related to your Flash Drive,

(2) For Persistence, select the option **Stored in reserved extra space** and adjust the slider to desired capacity

(4) Click the **Make Startup Disk** button: Proceed to Make an Ubuntu Startup Disk

[image]

A bar appears to indicate the progress of the install. Once the installation is complete, remove the CD, restart your computer and set your Boot Menu or System BIOS to boot from your USB device.

You should now be booting from your Ubuntu Startup Disk

I hope this will help you.

Comment: what you look for?