# how to install openssh from usb?

Tags: openssh

Hi I have installed ubuntu from bootable usb. During installation I did not pay attention for Openssh server in software selection screen. however is it possible to reboot from usb to just install openssh only without affecting anything which is already installed and configured? Just like we install feature/server role in windows!!!  Thanks. I dont have internet connection in my server yet. thanks.

Comment: Hi!

To do this please use sudo tasksel. But before that what is in your sources.list file? Upload it to [http://pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Armand Bozsik. What did you mean by "But before that what is in your sources.list file?". Servers are not accessible now, just asking, If I use 'tasksel' where the oppenssh source will come from? are these packages available in the server repository?

Comment: No. If you dont have internet connection you should install using apt-cdrom described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository)

Then if you successfully told APT to use this source instead of the online ones you can use the usual command to install.

Please note: the number of packages on a cd-rom are limited due to the size restrictions.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1403679

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `*.iso` of your Ubuntu, then the debian package can be retrieved.

1. First mount your iso:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/iso; sudo mount -o loop /path/to/iso /media/iso
   ```
2. Now, mount the squash present in the iso:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop /media/iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs /mnt
   ```
3. To retrieve your package, you need a tool called `dpkg-repack`

   ```
   dpkg-repack --root=/mnt openssh-server
   ```

Comment: my usb is visible on fdisk -l. but once i run mount command then it prompts error like file system not found. server file system ext2, but usb is FAT, any idea?

Comment: What is the exact command that you ran?

Answer (score 0):

Rather, you can download the .deb file on any other machine which is      connected to the Internet. Using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install download openssh-server
```

The, install the .deb image on the server using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/himanshu_code/Desktop/ssh.deb
```

Comment: himanshu, i dont have remote connectivity with my server, thats why i am trying to install openssh from usb.