# how to add kernel level routing?

Tags: networking

In my Ubuntu server I have 5 NICs for five different subnet. There are some default kernel level routing which needs to be modified. The problem is NIC's ip and destination network is different.

For instance one NIC ip is 10.172.89.2 and this NIC is supposed to transmit traffic to 10.214.7.35. If I try adding route like:

```
route add -network 10.214.7.35 mask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.172.89.2 dev eth0
```

then kernel does not accept this route saying `destination network unreachable`. Can anyone help giving idea please?

Comment: Don't just ask some question and begone..consider selecting any of the answers given as selected (given they solve your query) on [this question of yours](http://askubuntu.com/q/724925/216503)..

Comment: But there is no commentyet following my last comment. How I have been escaped!!! @heemay

Comment: default route get changed on reboot. Please help, I will appreciate.

Comment: Networking is not one of my strongest suites, i have edited the post..hope some of our in-house experts can help..btw go find [chili555](http://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) if you want a prompt solution, he is the one you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `-host` because your giving an network with netmask for only one host. Also I think the syntax is `-network 10.214.7.35/32`. Also I recommend to do it with the `ip` command, `route` is a bit rusty.

Comment: I tried to give an example ddio!! I have routes like 10.172.60.0/29 too and I get same prompt. I think command is not issue but its two different network, i dont know!! meaning NIC IP and destination network IP different!!!

Comment: ok, please give the output of "ip a" and "ip r" and example you would like to get to work. It's no problem that destination network is not the network your nic is in. It would be an problem if another nic is in the destination network...

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces
Auto em1
Iface em1 inet static
  Address 10.172.48.2
  Netmask 255.255.255.248
  Network 10.172.48.0
  Broadcast 10.172.48.7
      
Auto em2
Iface em2 inet static
   Address 10.172.67.2
   Netmask 255.255.255.240
   Network 10.172.48.0
   Broadcast 10.172.48.15

Comment: Netstat -rn
Net 0.0.0.0 gw 10.172.67.2 mask 0.0.0.0 iface em4. 
Net 10.172.48.0 gw 0.0.0.0 mask 29 iface em1
Net 10.172.66.0 gw 0.0.0.0 mask 29 iface em2
Net 10.172.67.0 gw 0.0.0.0 mask 28 iface em4
Net 10.172.241.0 gw 0.0.0.0 mask 29 iface em3
Net 10.172.186.0 gw 0.0.0.0 mask 29 iface em49. similarly 3 more. I dont have servers access now to run command.

Comment: Given the quality, this should be a comment, not an answer..

Comment: -host and -network 10.214.7.35/32 syntax worked for me. thx