# How should I manually install a gui to ubuntu server?

Tags: 20.04, gui, offline

I'm a RHEL admin but I've been given a task to test around with ubuntu server 20.04 and try to make sure it can do everything RHEL can.

I'm installing ubuntu server 20.04 on a VM, the Legacy ISO because these hosts cannot have access to the internet. I tried mounting the ubuntu desktop ISO with the apt=cdrom utility, but when i look in the pool directory of the ISO I cant find anything regarding gnome to install even though I know ubuntu-desktop comes with gnome. Do you guys have any pointers? all guides are pointing me to things that involve internet access and I cannot see the options for ubuntu-desktop with tasksel.

Very Respectfully,
your confused brother in Linux

Comment: Maybe an answer in here might work for you?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository

Comment: I would consider breaking the problem into two parts. First would be an online VM to see if Ubuntu meets your needs and which packages you prefer for your tasks and services. Online makes that experimentation and exploring and testing MUCH faster and easier. Second step would be to learn how to replicate your preferred configuration offline. Once you know what you want, offline is not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Gnome shell, that kind of means having a GUI front end. Ubuntu Server doesn't come with that. You can add it, as @Mlocik97 suggests. However, you are better to download a desktop version of Ubuntu and install that.

The server version of Ubuntu is supposed to be a command line front end. However, most of what you know and love on RHEL will work here. So if you are comfortable with those, press on.

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of ISO, but you can install it via APT, just install `gnome-shell` and `ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: OP said the machine isn't connected to the internet.