# Recover Ubuntu-Desktop via Live CD

Tags: live-cd, restore, cairo-dock

I was trying to uninstall the package `cairo-dock`. And I think I've uninstalled things I shouldnt. Now My 10.04 only starts in text mode.
What should I do to restore my GNOME desktop?

Is there any way to recover it via Live CD?

Comment: Possible duplicate ? - http://askubuntu.com/q/3576/6005

Comment: Do you really want to recover your machine using a Live CD? The contents are a little outdated, if you've an Internet connection, you should try that instead.

Comment: Its without internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Boot from the LiveCD, and then re-install the system ***without*** formatting the the partition so that your /home/* directory is safe.

***However***, as always, you should have a backup of your data.