# Install programs from USB

Tags: software-installation

I need to install programs in multiple computers but I can't use Internet. There's a way to install programs from USB?
(I have only one computer connected)

Comment: This might be worthwhile for you... http://askubuntu.com/questions/3576/how-to-make-usb-drive-as-local-repository

Comment: Similarly to how the Ubuntu LiveCD has a repository located on it, you could do something similar to your USB drive (as mentioned earlier).  You may also be interested in looking into [apt-cacher-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an installer file then all you have to do is copy that file onto the machine from USB and run it. If there are just a bunch of files that have to be manually installed then I suggest you write a shell script that will handle it and then you can open the USB and run it on each machine.

Answer (score 1):

Like Brian Sizemore said, most software comes in an installer, such as a .deb. fortunately, apt-get comes with an option to download software without installing it! first, open a terminal ctrl+alt+t, and use the command `apt-get download "name of software"` *(replace "name of software with the name of the software")* and it will download the software to your computer in your home directory. from there, you can move them to a flash drive. then when you want to install them, just open the files no the flash drive.

NOTE: most programs have dependencies. meaning, you have to install other programs first. so, if it says you have unmet dependencies, just repeat the process with the name of the dependencies