# Update Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS without internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I am new to Linux and currently run Ubuntu server with FOG for imaging computers. Due to policy reasons this server is not allowed to access the internet. I am in desperate need to update this server as well as install a desktop GUI without losing the images my predecessors have built. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

No idea about FOG and your company policy, but I suppose you could burn an image of ubuntu 16.04.3, burn it and add it to your sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and update.

Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3576/how-to-make-usb-drive-as-local-repository) posts.