# Linux-Headers Reinstall

Tags: linux-headers

I'm trying upgrade firefox but says that i need to reinstall linux-headers 4.4.0-98.I tried to install but that's it's what happens 'the package linux-headers needs to be reinstalled, but i can't find an archive for it'.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers 4.4.0-98` work? Or what does it complain?

Comment: can you paste the output of `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers 4.4.0-98` to your question?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: the package linux-headers 4.4.0-98 needs to be reinstaled, but i can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `apt-cache policy linux-headers-4.4.0-98`?

Comment: In the first command the package should be "linux-headers-4.4.0-98" so please include the minus character.

Comment: the output is linux-headers-4.4.0-98 Installed:4.4.0-98.121 Candidate:4.4.0-98.121 Version table: *** 4.4.0-98.121 100 100/var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: It might help, if you change settings in Software Sources dialog. What does `lsb_release -a` tell?

Comment: No LSB modules are avaliable Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Release:16.04 Codename: xenial

Comment: What do you have in "Download from" field in Ubuntu Software tab in Software & Updates dialog? Can you upload contents of your /etc/apt/sources.list in some pastebin and link it here?

Comment: I do not know, if you have the dialog in standard Ubuntu, but in Xubuntu there is and it can be launched e.g. by Settings... button in Software Updater's dialog.

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list return permission denied

Comment: What does command `dpkg-query -W -f='${status}\n' linux-headers-4.4.0-98` print? BTW please include '@jarno' in your reply so that I get notification.

Comment: @jarno install reinstreq half-installed

Answer (score 5):

**First try the fix-missing feature**

```
sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing
```

**Second, try to install headers from the command line:**

Maybe you just need these specific headers (linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic):

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
```

If that doesn't work, see what kernel type you are using (generic, lowlatency, etc.):

```
uname -r
```

This will return something like "4.15.0-30-generic" or "4.15.0-30-lowlatency". Install/Reinstall the headers that correspond to your kernel type. Eg if it is the generic kernel (most likely):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
```

This will cause the current headers for your current kernel to be automatically installed and upgraded.

**If above doesn't work, try the following:**

Update to latest kernel:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Reboot to ensure you are using latest kernel.

Purge out old headers and removed unused apps/kernels:

```
sudo apt remove --purge linux-headers-*
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Reinstall the headers:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: uname -r returned 4.4.0-98-generic but after typing the command keeps saying that needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: added more to answer.... let me know if that helps

Comment: I don't understand whats happening.Anything i try to do(install, upgrade) give me the same message, that linux-headers 4.4.0-98 needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: try  sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: @lippman27 That is an old kernel. Do you have newer one installed? (`dpkg -l linux-image-4'*' | grep ^ii` will tell)

Comment: my version is 4.4.0-98

Comment: `linux-headers-generic` Might want to install the incorrect headers, at least in my case it was like that. Better to write your kernel version directly -> `linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic`

Comment: This is truly maddening. There are no headers for my kernel, period. I cannot find anything that works. kernel version `4.19.0-25-amd64`. Using just amd64 without a version number, there are no packages. Using that whole string, there are no packages. Using 'linux' as the first word of the package name, there are no packages. Using 'kernel' instead of 'linux', there are no packages. I've lost an entire day of my life on this. There are no packages. There are no packages. There are no packages. Period. Why is absolutely nobody anywhere able to explain how to install the headers?????

Comment: @JohnSmith the package name needs to be exact, so just guessing probably won't work. usually if you `apt install linux-headers-generic` it should install and update the appropriate headers for your system.

Answer (score 0):

These commands worked for me.

### Find `linux-headers-4.4.0-98`

```
$ apt-cache search linux-headers-4.4.0-98
linux-headers-4.4.0-98 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-98-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

### Install `linux-headers-4.4.0-98`

For your reinstall you will type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
```

But for myself it's a new package so I'll use:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-98
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-98 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 78.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-98 all 4.4.0-98.121 [9,913 kB]
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic amd64 4.4.0-98.121 [793 kB]
Fetched 10.7 MB in 3s (3,463 kB/s)                  
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-98.
(Reading database ... 288111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-98_4.4.0-98.121_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-98 (4.4.0-98.121) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic_4.4.0-98.121_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-98 (4.4.0-98.121) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
```

### Remove `linux-headers-4.4.0-98`

Because this was a test and I don't need them on my machine:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-98
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 7,431 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 314874 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic, directory '/lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic' not empty so not removed
```

### Cleanup leftover garbage

I see there is left over garbage in the last line so I'll manually clean it up:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic
$ ll /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic
ls: cannot access '/lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic': No such file or directory
```

Now `4.4.0-98` is almost removed. It is completely removed with:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't worked

Comment: @lippman27 Do you have enough free space? Use `df -h /boot` to confirm. Thanks.

Comment: yes only 2% use 840G avaliable

Answer (score 0):

**If you have internet connection...**

Run `software-properties-gtk`. In Ubuntu Software tab, notice the Download from field. What do you have there? (I use "ubuntu.trumpetti.atm.tut.fi/ubuntu" as I live in Finland; at least that server has linux-headers-4.4.0-98 currently.) Try to change the setting in the field. In Updates tab see that you have "Important security updates" checked. Do what the dialog asks. And close it. Then do the following in terminal (but stop, if there are errors and please report them in comments.):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-98
sudo apt-mark auto linux-headers-4.4.0-98
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

and run `update-manager` to install further updates.

**If you do not have internet connnection...**

If the problem is that you do not have internet connection, but you have Ubuntu CD-ROM/DVD installation media, you can use it as a software source, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#CD-ROM.2FDVD). If you do not have optical media, but USB one, trye [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/947299/21005).

Check if the media contains some other kernel:

```
apt-cache policy linux-generic
```

If it contains different version, you had better purge the 4.4.0-98 headers:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq linux-headers-4.4.0-98 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
```

And install the kernel from the media:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

And finally purge the old kernel images:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic
```

Comment: after run software-properties-gtk the application stops, andinformation about avaliable software is out-of-date but i don't have an internet connection which it's another problem i'm having

Comment: @lippman27 I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

After trying many of the options above, (perhaps it helped) I tried the following command and it worked:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I hope it works of others...

Comment: There are other more complete answers already.