# The package linux-headers-5.15.0-50 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management, upgrade, kernel, updates

I have ready many questions and answers related to linux-headers here but cannot solve it. Basically I'm trying to run sudo apt upgrade on my Ubuntu Server Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-48-generic x86_64).

Everytime I get this error message:

```
The package linux-headers-5.15.0-50 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

From my understanding it seems to have been removed from the repo? What do I do now because I'm stuck

Comment: I'll suggest performing maintenance on your system more regularly than you do, as 22.04.1 implies you've not applied security fixes since at least February-2023, as https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ shows the release date of Ubuntu 22.04.2 ISOs for new installs, but installed systems upgraded in the weeks before that date.  *Current package is `linux-generic | 5.15.0.73.71           | jammy-security   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux-Headers Reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064674/linux-headers-reinstall)

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. From what I've found online this linux header was removed from the ubuntu repo?