# Installing local deb files with all dependencies

Tags: 18.04, deb

On a PC with no internet connection I have local .deb files of some packages stored in individual folders. At present I copy all `.deb` files of a package to `var/cache/apt/archives/` then run `sudo apt install package=version`to sort dependencies for me and to make sure the package would install the local version I have and not update. I do this for the rest of the packages I needed to install locally. My question would be is there a 'cleaner' way of doing this?
I tried copying all my deb files to the `var/cache/apt/archives` folder and using

```
`# echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' \
> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs`
```

To keep my deb files and at least install all the packages in one go instead of copying then installing individually. But the above does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleaner way would be to create your own private PPA, as outlined [in this Askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3576/how-to-make-usb-drive-as-local-repository) or, perhaps better, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository).

Manually putting all the debs in the cache `var/cache/apt/archives/` may indeed not be so "clean", but nevertheless can work if all required debs are locally present, and especially since you are also specifying the version to install: `apt` (or `apt-get`) first looks in the cache before attempting to go out on the internet.