# Install VMware tools

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools

I have an ubuntu vm on VMware ESXi, When I try to install VMware tools it is grayed out, I make sure it is not installed.

Note: I install Ubuntu server 23.04 from USB stick.
Also there no internet connection
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is easier and better to install open-vm-tools from the Ubuntu repositories. Just open a virtual console to your VM and `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install open-vm-tools` to use the operating system managed vmtools instead.

See https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803 for more.

Comment: Just saw that you have no internet access from the VM. You can still manage to get open-vm-tools installed using an .iso image. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/3576/how-to-make-usb-drive-as-local-repository for ideas on that.

Comment: after I installed VMware tools in that method where can I found the folder to extract its content?